# Right usage of move semantics

Tags: c++

because of performance reasons I want to use move semantics in this part of code:

```
resultVector.push_back(GetEntry<T>(m, columnIndex, &readData));
delete[] readData.data;
```

It would look like this:

```
resultVector.push_back(std::move(GetEntry<T>(m, columnIndex, &readData)));
delete[] readData.data;
```

But I am not sure if it will result in undefinied behavior because of the `delete[] readData.data;` afterwards.

Here is the `GetEntry` function:

```
template<typename T>
T GetEntry(int line, int col, hdfData<T> *hdfData) {
    int n_max = hdfData->dims[1];
    return hdfData->data[n_max * line + col];
}
```

Comment: The `std::move` doesn't do anything in your code.

Comment: Prefer `emplace_back` over `push_back`.

Comment: Move semantics deals with ownership. If you intend to move something into something else, it's because you intend to give it ownership. `delete` and `delete[]` can only be used when you are the sole owner of an object. If you *just* gave ownership away, it's hard to imagine a scenario where deleting it right away is the right thing to do. Maybe I misunderstand what `GetEntry` is meant to do though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use `std::move` in this case.  `GetEntry` returns by value meaning your call to `push_back` will call the rvalue reference overload and will move the object automatically.

The only time you need to use `move` is when you explicitly want to move a lvalue (named object).